# Why does xpath not return this XML node?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

So I have code that looks like this:

```
content_url = 'http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/index.rss'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(content_url))
bq = doc.xpath('//item')
```

But it returns `bq` as empty.

I know for sure that it has that tag though, this is the first few tags on that page:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:ev="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/event/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:syn="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">
<channel rdf:about="http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/index.rss">...</channel>
<item rdf:about="http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/3012277218.html">...</item>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *item* is not in the default namespace, you need to tell XPath under what namespace to look under.

First off, your namespace is what the `xmlns` attribute is set to. For Craigslist, it appears to be `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/`. So that would be the namespace you have to tell XPath that you want to use.

When calling XPath though, we have to specify what the extra namespaces that we want to use are. Like so.

```
doc.xpath('//item', { 'rdf' => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/' })
```

That is not it though, we need to tell XPath that item is under the `rdf` namespace. We can do this by prefixing the tag name with the namespace. Like so.

```
doc.xpath('//rdf:item', { 'rdf' => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/' })
```

Comment: How do I find children of the `item` node? e.g. `<title>`? I tried `//rdf:item/title`, but that doesn't work. Do I have to prefix every child tag with `rdf:`?

Comment: For instance, how would I parse this tag that is a child of the `<item>` tag - `<dc:date>2012-06-03T14:50:43-07:00</dc:date>`. I tried `/rdf:dc:date` and that threw an error. Thoughts?

Comment: @marcamillion. Use `//rdf:item/dc:date`. In xpath, elements are seperated by `/`. An element has one and only one namespace, which can be declared on a parent or on the element itself. The namespace can be implied, in case a `xmlns='...'` occurs on a parent, or explicit (as in your example). But remember: one and only one namespace per element, elements are seperated by `/`.

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with namespaces. You could do:

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
```

or you can just use

```
doc.css('item')
```

instead

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to remove all the namespaces. This way you don't select something under a different namespace.

Comment: Right, from the question he seemed to want every item element.

Comment: His example is pretty straight forward, but it is _easier to learn good habits_ then it is to _unlearn bad habits._

Comment: I prefer my way actually, it reduces screen clutter/finger fatigue

Comment: Although this way doesn't work, I still upvoted you so you don't lose points :)

Comment: Removing the namespaces is a brute force way of working around the problem. Using CSS to allow us to ignore namespaces is a very valid way of going, as long as you are sure that the namespaces aren't providing anything useful. Namespaces have their place but sometimes they get in the way or needlessly complicate the code or task of retrieving data. Nokogiri's use of CSS steps around that nicely.

Comment: I agree with @the tin man. I don't understand the comment that this way doesn't work.

Comment: @pguardiario, both solutions you provided do work fine. Removing the namespace is heavy-handed and CSS is the more elegant way to go about it. Using the namespace + tag in XPath is the correct way to do it but it's of little use when you know you need to use every tag in the file and don't need to separate out one space from another. That's especially true in RDF and RSS content.